# how to run g++ and show the results in a horizontal split in VIM

Tags: vim, g++

I use this command :!g++ % -g -lm && a.exe & pause
The result comes out in a new command prompt. I'm using gvim7.3. How can i make VIM to display the result in the same window (horizontal split)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

:make then :copen should do the trick. You can also close the window with :cclose.

Comment: Or `:make %:r` which will work even without a makefile present.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
:new +r\ !g++\ #\ -g\ -lm
```

That opens a new "window" and reads the output of the g++ command into it.  Note that you need to use # instead of % because you have switch to a new buffer.

I'm not sure how to get && to work, so I would just create a script that compiles and executes.

You might want to also do "set nomod" so you can close that window without saving the file.

Comment: The thing is i wanna get results from execution at the bottom of the window. Compile, run and get the result at the bottom. Is it possible?

Comment: Try `:r !g++ % -g -lm`. (Again, that doesn't actually run it.)

Comment: What do you mean by at the bottom of the window?  Do you not want it in what vim calls a window (what you get from :new)?

Comment: @TimK, not from :new, what i was saying was i don't want new command prompt popping up, i want to run on the same screen where we type our ex commands, when i type a command or enter, it moves back to my code to edit, it doesn't need to be in two windows. Previously, i had what i want, i formatted my computer and installed new vim, it happens. So, i'm curious how to fix. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

From my `.vimrc`, a function that does similar to what you want.  I use vim not gvim, so hopefully it still uses the same convention for working directory.  You'll need to be using the `filetype` plugin for the autocommands to work (the function calls the `<F6>` one so be aware of that).  This switches to quickfix mode if there was a compile error.  Also it runs the program with an input file is one is present (should be obvious how to remove that functionality).  Very much a work-in-progress so comments are welcome!

```
function! MakeAndRun()
  w
  let progName = expand('%:r')
  if filereadable(progName . '.in')
    let shCmd = 'time ./' . progName . ' < ' . progName . '.in 2>&1'
  else
    let shCmd = 'time ./' . progName . ' 2>&1'
  endif

  execute "normal \<F6>"
  call setqflist([])
  redraw | echo 'Compiling ' . progName

  silent! belowright new Run\ results
  setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile nowrap nonumber 
  autocmd WinEnter <buffer> if winnr('$') == 1 | :q! | endif

  execute 'silent %! make ' . progName
  if v:shell_error
    setlocal buftype=quickfix
    cbuffer
    execute 'wincmd p'
    setlocal statusline=%qRun\ results
  else
    resize 4
    redraw | echo 'Running program...<CTRL-C> to abort'

    execute 'silent $read !'. shCmd
  endif

  normal gg
  execute 'resize ' . min([12, line('$')+1])
  execute 'wincmd p'
endfunction

autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :call MakeAndRun()<CR>
autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <F6> :if bufexists('Run results')\
                                                       \| execute bufwinnr('^Run results$') . 'wincmd w'\
                                                       \| :q!\
                                                       \| endif<CR>
autocmd FileType cpp imap <buffer> <F5> <C-O><F5>
autocmd FileType cpp imap <buffer> <F6> <C-O><F6>
```